# Looping nested json in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the nested `json` as below. I need to iterate the `json` and have to get each value.

```
{
    "processDefId": "xyz",
    "name": "name",
    "sla": "10",
    "hasChild": true,
    "child": [
        {
            "activityDefId": "siteSurveyDef",
            "activityName": "Site Survey",
            "isMandatory": "true",
            "isOptional": "false",
            "sla": "10",
            "sequence": "1",
            "hasChild": true,
            "child": [
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Begin",
                    "activityName": "Begin",
                    "isMandatory": "true",
                    "isOptional": "false",
                    "sla": "10",
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "hasChild": true
                },
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Site Survey2",
                    "activityName": "Site Survey2",
                    "isMandatory": "true",
                    "isOptional": "false",
                    "sla": "10",
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "hasChild": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "activityDefId": "siteSurvey",
            "activityName": "Procurement",
            "isMandatory": "true",
            "isOptional": "false",
            "sla": "10",
            "sequence": "1",
            "hasChild": true,
            "child": [
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Begin",
                    "activityName": "Begin"
                },
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Site Survey",
                    "activityName": "Site Survey3",
                    "isMandatory": "true",
                    "isOptional": "false",
                    "sla": "10",
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "hasChild": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "activityDefId": "siteSurvey",
            "activityName": "Provisioning",
            "isMandatory": "true",
            "isOptional": "false",
            "sla": "10",
            "sequence": "1",
            "hasChild": true,
            "child": [
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Begin",
                    "activityName": "Begin"
                },
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Site Survey",
                    "activityName": "Site Survey4",
                    "isMandatory": "true",
                    "isOptional": "false",
                    "sla": "10",
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "hasChild": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to loop like this:

```
$.each(hiddenJson, function() {
    $.each(this, function(name, value) {
        //var sla = me.sla;//use `this` from outer scope
        //alert(sla);
        console.log(name + '=' + value);

    });  
});
```

I am not getting value properly.Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok `Recursively` you can do it,

```
var j = {
    "processDefId": "xyz",
    "name": "name",
    "sla": "10",
    "hasChild": true,
    "child": [
        {
            "activityDefId": "siteSurveyDef",
            "activityName": "Site Survey",
            "isMandatory": "true",
            "isOptional": "false",
            "sla": "10",
            "sequence": "1",
            "hasChild": true,
            "child": [
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Begin",
                    "activityName": "Begin",
                    "isMandatory": "true",
                    "isOptional": "false",
                    "sla": "10",
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "hasChild": true
                },
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Site Survey2",
                    "activityName": "Site Survey2",
                    "isMandatory": "true",
                    "isOptional": "false",
                    "sla": "10",
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "hasChild": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "activityDefId": "siteSurvey",
            "activityName": "Procurement",
            "isMandatory": "true",
            "isOptional": "false",
            "sla": "10",
            "sequence": "1",
            "hasChild": true,
            "child": [
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Begin",
                    "activityName": "Begin"
                },
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Site Survey",
                    "activityName": "Site Survey3",
                    "isMandatory": "true",
                    "isOptional": "false",
                    "sla": "10",
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "hasChild": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "activityDefId": "siteSurvey",
            "activityName": "Provisioning",
            "isMandatory": "true",
            "isOptional": "false",
            "sla": "10",
            "sequence": "1",
            "hasChild": true,
            "child": [
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Begin",
                    "activityName": "Begin"
                },
                {
                    "activityDefId": "Site Survey",
                    "activityName": "Site Survey4",
                    "isMandatory": "true",
                    "isOptional": "false",
                    "sla": "10",
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "hasChild": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

function recursiveDecode(obj){

  $.each(obj, function(n, v) {

    if(typeof v === 'object'){
      recursiveDecode(v);
    }  
    else{
      console.log(n +'='+v);
    }

  });

};

recursiveDecode(j);
```